# VSCode using Comic Sans font for it's interface

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for years and never seen this before.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw3H4.png

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, but the problem persists.

Before I re-installed I deleted every code folder I could find in my AppData folders, but when I re-installed all my extensions etc came back straight away, so I think I might have missed a folder somewhere.

Can someone point me to where I should look to nuke all traces of VSCode so I can re-install it, not sign in with sync and start completely fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone finds this in the future, I had installed a tweaker for Windows called [Windhawk](https://windhawk.net/) which can let you tweak things, one of the things you can tweak is VSCode. Seems like I enabled that tweak and by default it changes the interface font to Comic Sans. ‍♂️

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipIMu.png

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me a lot of troubleshooting time - I had the exact same issue, I enabled it in Windhawk and completely forgot about it.